# ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.describe) HTTPError 404: The Cloud SQL instance does not exist, but it does exist?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm getting this error:

ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.describe) HTTPError 404: The Cloud SQL instance does not exist.

When calling:

gcloud sql instances describe my-project

from my windows cmd within the Google Cloud SDK Shell. However, when I look at my instances on my Google Cloud Platform interface I can see that the corresponding instance. All indicates that it DOES exist. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Is your CloudSQL instance really named my-project?

Comment: No haha, just using that as a 'foobar'

Comment: I wanted to confirm you were using the CloudSQL instance name here and not the project name. But if my-project is indeed the instance name, then the error could also be due to your Cloud SDK using the wrong project. Try with the `--project` flag set to the correct project.

Comment: @LundinCast that actually solved my problem, you should submit it as an answer imho

Answer (score 12):

LundinCast had the right answer in comments. Your problem can be resolved by following the instance name with `--project="[projectname]"`.

Answer (score 7):

Try to run following to list your instances:

```
gcloud sql instances list
```